# UI Button with Image Smaller than Touchable Area

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uibutton, uiimage

I've not much response so am adding some more info.

My buttons are not rectangular, nor organised in a grid so I need a way of creating what looks like a button (and shows that it has been pressed visually, as per a standard UIButton) but where the touchable area is different to the image area.

I am using a transparent PNG and that element works fine.  I've added the buttons in Interface Builder and am wondering if that is the problem.

However, if I change imageEdgeInsets, it distorts the image display, which is obviously not what I want.

Bizarrely, if I increase the dimemsions of the button, it doesn't change the image, but if I decrease them it does.

I have tried different combinations of mode (scale to fill etc), but to no avail.

I am aware that there is an image and background image property, but in IB there is only one.

Essentially, I don't understand how the geometry works and the Apple documentation doesn't seem to help.

Surely, I can't be the only person to try to do this.  Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Many thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Just a thought, but before you go crazy see if using the backgroundImage rather than the image might give you the effect you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I stumbled across Ole Begemann's [Non-rectangular buttons class](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/).  It just does what I need - to be able to create buttons where the touchable area follows the visible element of a non rectangular image.

@Helium3 - thanks - that allowed me to use a larger touch area, bit not a smaller one.

Comment: Ahh, ok you want to have a button touch area which is smaller than the image?Invisible buttons over UIImages is what I use, creating the illusion of a button.

Comment: and how do you do the trick with selected state (darker image)

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the buttons setting to Aspect Fit. This will fill the button with your image so a smaller image than the button size would leave the space around the image.

Also set the button type to custom.

[image]

Comment: The Button "Image" gets centered and the "Background" gets stretched, still a good solution